Unit Test - CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY
H**ello,
**
My unit test return this error **TestUpdateAccountCA.test  TestDataFactory system.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 801WU00000JRtwkYAD; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CalcultateAmount: execution of BeforeUpdate
caused Constructor not defined: [OrderNetAmountService].(List): []                                                                                                                                           Class.TestUpdateAccountCA.test: line 24,
I create apex class service AccountCA for to update a custom field 'chiffre-d'affaire" on Account records based on the total revenue generated from associated Orders, class TestDataFactory for create elements, but I don't understant why my asserts it's not good.
Thank you for your help.
I would like a lead that could unlock my code.
@isTest
private class TestUpdateAccountCA {

    @isTest static void test() {
        // Create test data
        Account testAccount = TestDataFactory.createAccount('Account 1');
        Product2 testProduct = TestDataFactory.createProduct2('Produit 1');
        PricebookEntry testPriceBookEntry = TestDataFactory.createPricebookEntry(testProduct.Id);
        Order testOrder = TestDataFactory.createOrder(testAccount.Id);
        OrderItem testOrderItem1 = TestDataFactory.createOrderItem(testOrder.Id, testPriceBookEntry.Id, 10, 150);
        OrderItem testOrderItem2 = TestDataFactory.createOrderItem(testOrder.Id, testPriceBookEntry.Id, 20, 1000);

        Test.startTest();

        // Update the order status
        testOrder.Status = 'Ordered'; 
        update testOrder; // Line 24

        Test.stopTest();

        // Calculate expected total revenue
        Decimal expectedRevenue = (testOrderItem1.Quantity * testOrderItem1.UnitPrice) + (testOrderItem2.Quantity * testOrderItem2.UnitPrice);

        // ASSERT
        Account updatedAccount = [SELECT Id, Chiffre_d_affaire__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :testAccount.Id LIMIT 1];
        System.assertEquals(expectedRevenue, updatedAccount.Chiffre_d_affaire__c, 'The account revenue should be updated correctly.');
    }
}



public with sharing class TestDataFactory {

    public static Account createAccount(String name) {
        Account acc = new Account(Name = name);
        insert acc;
        return acc;
        
    }
    
    public static Account createAccountWithMultipleOrders (Integer numberOfOrders){

        Account accs = new Account(Name = 'Test Account 2');
        insert accs;

        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();

           for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfOrders; i++) {
               Order order = new Order(
                AccountId = accs.Id,
                Status = 'Draft',
                Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
                EffectiveDate = Date.today(),
                Name = 'Test Order ' + i
               );
               orders.add(order);
           }
           
           // Insère toutes les commandes
           insert orders;
           return accs;

    }

    public static Product2 createProduct2(String name) {
        Product2 prod = new Product2(
            Name = name,
            Family = 'Chemise'
        );
        insert prod;
        return prod;
    }

    public static PricebookEntry createPricebookEntry(Id productId) {
        PricebookEntry pbooke = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
            Product2Id = productId,
            UnitPrice = 1020,
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert pbooke;
        return pbooke;
    }

    public static Order createOrder(Id accountId) {
        Order testOrder = new Order(
            Name = 'Test Order',
            AccountId = accountId,
            Status = 'Draft',
            Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
            EffectiveDate = Date.today()
        );
        insert testOrder;
        return testOrder;
    }

    public static OrderItem createOrderItem(Id orderId, Id pricebookEntryId, Integer quantity, Decimal unitPrice) {
        OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(
            OrderId = orderId,
            PricebookEntryId = pricebookEntryId,
            Quantity = quantity,
            UnitPrice = unitPrice
        );
        insert orderItem;
        return orderItem;
    }
}

public with sharing class AccountCAService {
    public static void processOrdersUpdateAccount(Map<Id, Order> oldOrders, List<Order> newOrders) {
      
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>(); 
        Map<Id, Decimal> accountAmount = new Map<Id, Decimal>(); 

        for (Order ord : newOrders) {
            if (ord.AccountId != null) {
                 
                Decimal oldAmount = oldOrders != null && oldOrders.containsKey(ord.Id) ? oldOrders.get(ord.Id).TotalAmount : 0;
              
                Decimal difference = ord.TotalAmount - oldAmount;

                if (!accountAmount.containsKey(ord.AccountId)) {
                    accountAmount.put(ord.AccountId, 0);
                }
                accountAmount.put(ord.AccountId, accountAmount.get(ord.AccountId) + difference);
            }
        }

        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
         
        for (Id accountId : accountAmount.keySet()) {
            Account acc = [SELECT Id, Chiffre_d_affaire__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId FOR UPDATE]; // Gérer les conflits d'update
              
            acc.Chiffre_d_affaire__c += accountAmount.get(accountId);
            accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
        }

        if (!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update accountsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}


    public static void calculateNetAmount(List<Order> orders) {
        
        if (orders == null || orders.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        for (Order order : orders) {
            
            if (order.TotalAmount != null && order.ShipmentCost__c != 
 null) {
              
                order.NetAmount__c = order.TotalAmount - order.ShipmentCost__c;
            }
        }

        
    }
}


The test class you pasted doesn't even have line 34? Which line would the error be at? At a glance it all looks OK-ish (the service is called from anywhere? Order trigger? And the trigger runs on what after update?) If you look at debug log - what lines get executed before it throws the error? I don't think it even reaches the assert

@eyescream the service is called from trigger on order, after update. The trigger runs on object Account for update  custom field (CA).

this is my trigger :
`
trigger UpdateAccountCA on Order (after update) {
AccountCAService.processOrdersUpdateAccount(Trigger.new);

}
`

I don't see anything that would crash on line 34 in what you pasted. You sure it saved the test OK? What code sits in the line 34 of TestUpdateAccountCA in your org?

Now I don't have the seem error I have this : TestUpdateAccountCA.test  TestDataFactory  @eyescream

caused by: line 9, column 5: Constructor not defined: [OrderNetAmountService].(List): []                                                                      Class.TestUpdateAccountCA.test: line 24,

Line 24 for TestUpdateAccountCa it's " update testOrder;", beacause in my classe OrderNetAmountService, which aims to calculate the net amount (NetAmount__c) of a list of orders.

@eyescream I update my publication with new error and I put comments for line error

You renamed the class from AccountCAService to OrderNetAmountService? I don't understand you, you're all over the place. That new call (in trigger I guess?) probably should look like OrderNetAmountService.calculateNetAmount(trigger.new);

@eyescream I have two service class for orders and account, sorry I share and I add code of class service to Order for understand error yes write like that for my trigger OrderNetAmountService
